# Is it possible to refresh PowerPivot files with out SharePoint?

Tags: sql, sharepoint, powerpivot

Is it possible to refresh PowerPivot files with out SharePoint and with out opening the file?

I have googled everything, and I don't want to install an instance of SharePoint, even a free version.

Answer (score 0):

You can host Power Pivot workbooks on a Power BI site.

Additionally you can check out [Power Update](http://www.powerpivotpro.com/2015/02/introducing-power-update/), and see if that makes sense for your use case.

Comment: Sure, but Power BI is going to change. See my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33890726/share-and-protect-online-an-excel-document-using-powerpivot-without-sharepoin

Comment: We can address questions asked in other threads, but that's not what you're asking here. The Power BI portal hit general availability in July 2015, and has monthly updates. The modeling engine is Power Pivot, except it receives more updates more quickly. New features are developed for Power Pivot in the Power BI Desktop app before Power Pivot for Excel. What features do you need that are lacking in the Power BI portal?

Additionally, you can check out Power Update, as linked in the answer I provided here.

Maybe if you told us what your requirements are, rather than aren't, we could help more.